# Auto button press based on value of Scope Variable using CSJS / SSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages, ssjs

I have page pendingData.xsp, when user clicks on adjust button system sets value of scope variable and move to page adjustpending.xsp. On adjustpending.xsp I want to press button retreive data automatically based on value of scope variable e.g. if scope variable is having value true than click button otherwise not. 
I am unable to find any event where variable can be checked and button pressed.

Following CSJS code is working perfectly fine but on change, focus, mouse over or other events of field etc. Moreover I have also tried on  this code on On Client load but failed to achieve desired results.

document.getElementById('#{id:button7}').click();

Can any body guide me how to address this issue.

Thanks in advance

Best Regards,
Qaiser

Comment: Do you have jQuery available, or are you willing to use it?

Comment: no only SSJS or CSJS. Kindly let me know if i can use jQuery as I don't know much about it.

Comment: Why "auto press" a button? You can run the code in e.g. the beforeRenderResponse event instead.

Comment: I ask because I have done it in jQuery, but in my case is wasn't possible any other way. You should consider Per's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @PerHenrikLausten I have used the same code after page load event of my control and it works perfectly fine but issue is that I close and open my custom control its shows window containing following. Problem Occurred   An Error occurred. see error log for more details. java.lang.ClassCaseException. Please let me know why system is throwing this exception in design mode.

Comment: Even if I add simple condition having single statement it shows same exception.

Answer (score 1):

I realise I'm not directly answering your question, but you'd probably be better off putting your code into a function and then calling that directly.
If the button needs to run it, just make the button call it directly. You can include this in a SSJS script library or in a scrips block on the xpage.

example ..

library code:

```
function doSomething() {
 // .. does something
}
```

button code :

```
doSomething()
```

beforePageLoad (or whichever is best event) :

```
doSomething()
```

This is ultimately the same as auto-clicking a button, but your doDomething() routine is now available to be called from wherever you like without having to figure out how to auto click a button.

Comment: thanks for prompt response and suggestion but please let me know procedure to get button object and press using SSJS?